# How to implement API to return a nested JSON?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, rest

I'm completely new to APIs and recently developed my first one using Spring Boot. So far, I've achieved to retrieve all records in a h2 in-memory database as a list of Jsons but because I'll try to fetch them with React and display them in a tree graph using D3, I also need to get them in a nested JSON format.

This is my code so far:

Alien.java

```
package com.example.alien.model;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
public class Alien {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String planet;
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Alien.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="parentId")
    private Optional<Alien> parent;
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Alien.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="parent", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Alien> children;

    public List<Alien> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
    public void setChildren(List<Alien> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }
    public Optional<Alien> getParent() {
        return parent;
    }
    public void  setParent(Optional<Alien> parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public String getPlanet() {
        return planet;
    }
    public void setPlanet(String planet) {
        this.planet = planet;
    }

}
```

AlienDto.java

```
package com.example.aliendto;

import java.util.Optional;

import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

import com.example.alien.model.Alien;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

public class AlienDto {
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String planet;
    private Integer parentId = 0;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getPlanet() {
        return planet;
    }

    public Integer getParentId() {
        return parentId;
    }
}
```

AlienController.java

```
package com.example.alien.controller;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.alien.dao.AlienRepo;
import com.example.alien.model.Alien;
import com.example.aliendto.AlienDto;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RestController
public class AlienController 
{   
    @Autowired
    AlienRepo repo;

    @PutMapping("/alien/{id}")
    public Alien updateAlien(@RequestBody Alien alien) {
        repo.save(alien);
        return alien;
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/alien/{id}")
    public String deleteAlien(@PathVariable Integer id)
    {
        Alien a = repo.getOne(id);
        repo.delete(a);
        return "deleted";
    }

     @PostMapping("/alien")
     public Alien addAlien(@RequestBody AlienDto dto) {
         Alien alien = new Alien();
         alien.setName(dto.getName());
         alien.setType(dto.getType());
         alien.setPlanet(dto.getPlanet());

         if(dto.getParentId() == 0) {
             alien.setParent(null);
         }else {
             Optional<Alien> parent = this.repo.findById(dto.getParentId());
             alien.setParent(parent);
         }
            repo.save(alien);
            return alien;
        } 

    @GetMapping("/aliens")
    public List<Alien> getAliens() {
        return repo.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/alien/{id}")
    public Optional<Alien> oneAlien(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        return repo.findById(id);
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home()
    {
        return "do_Ob";
    }
}
```

AlienRepo.java

```
package com.example.alien.dao;


import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.example.alien.model.Alien;

public interface AlienRepo extends JpaRepository<Alien, Integer>
{
}
```

Now I get the results like this on localhost:8080/aliens

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Javier","type":"Alpha","planet":"Earth","children":"Laia"}, 
 {"id":2,"name":"Javier","type":"Alpha","planet":"Earth","children":"John"},
{"id":3,"name":"Laia","type":"Omega","planet":"Earth","children":""},
{"id":4,"name":"John","type":"Omega","planet":"Earth","children":""}]]
```

But I ALSO would like to get them in another route like this:

```
[{"name":"Javier",
  "type":"Alpha",
  "planet":"Earth",
  "children":[{"name": "Laia", "type":"Omega",....},
              {"name": "John", "type":"Omega",....}]]
```

It'd also be okay if I could transform the JSON list to nested Json using React.

Thanks

Edit:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZoTI.png - Postman Output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make couple of changes to make it hierarchical, please check as below :

1. Add extra column 'parent' to maintain hierarchy

   ```
   @JsonIgnore
   @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Alien .class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "parentId")
   private Alien parent;
   ```
2. As mentioned by Gaurav please change `private String children;` as below

   ```
       @JsonIgnore
       @OneToMany(targetEntity = Alien .class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = 
       "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
       private List<Alien> children;
   ```
3. As we have added one extra column to maintain hierarchy you also need to make changes 
   in you POST and PUT, while creating resource you need to pass parent_id

   `if(alien.getParentId() == 0) {
                           alien.setParent(null);
                       }else {
                           Alien parent = this.repo.findById(alien.getParentId());
                           alien.setParent(parent);
                       }`

Edit : DTO, normally we use to map request data.

to work above code you need map requestbody to dto object which will have name, other properties, parentId and then create "Alien" object from dto.

a -> New Dto

public class AlientDto {

```
private String name;
private String type;
private String planet;
private int parentId = 0;

// Getter Setter
```

}

b-> Controller change

```
 @PostMapping("/alien")
     public Alien addAlien(@RequestBody AlienDto dto) {
         Alien alien = new Alien();
         alien.name(dto.getName());
         alien.type(dto.getType());
         alien.planet(dto.getPlanet());

         if(dto.getParentId() == 0) {
             alien.setParent(null);
         }else {
             Alien parent = this.repo.findById(dto.getParentId());
             alien.setParent(parent);
         }
            repo.save(alien);
            return alien;
        }
```

**or**

Update above code as below

```
  Alien parent = this.repo.findById(<pass parent id here>); // parent id is will be any alien id
                        alien.setParent(parent);
                    }
```

you can not have parent and parent_id at the same time

Parent :  Alien entity only which is parent to some other alien

parentId : Is a unique id for parent

for example :
[image: Alien]

Here we have created hierarchy 
      Alien1 does not have any parent 
      Alien1 is parent of Alien2
      Alien2 is parent of Alien3 and Alien4

Comment: Many thanks! I think I'm close to get it. Can I ask what is dto inside findById? And, why sometimes you use parentId and others just parent? I don't understand the role of parentId here. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, I got the following error after adding your code. "Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.example.alien.model.Alien column: parent_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")"

Comment: I fixed that by adding @Column(name="parentId", insertable=false, updatable=false)

Comment: Yeah sorry I missed to add that. The cleaner way ia that create a dto object with all required properties and then map dto object with alien entity. With this approach you don't need this parent_id field in entity

Comment: Are you able to get th desired result ?

Comment: If I now do a POST with the following query, shouldn't it work?     { "name": "Datta2811",
        "planet": "Earth",
        "type": "Alpha",
        "parentId": 0
    } Because I get no response from the server error 500

Comment: Still java.lang.NullPointerException: null. I think the problem lies in if(alien.getParentId() == 0) {
            alien.setParent(null);
        }, as It breaks  when I pass parentId = 0

Comment: Now It lets me write to h2 if I pass parentId: 0 but it neither adds column parent or children. If I pass a value different than 0 I get ""message": "Error accessing field [private java.lang.String com.example.alien.model.Alien.name] by reflection for persistent property [com.example.alien.model.Alien#name] :  By the way, I changed my primary key to name instead of id. It shouldn't be a problem as now I have parentName instead of parentId

Comment: Above code should work fine. Well few things you need to figure out. Thanks

Comment: Mark answer in case you find it helpful

Comment: If I access the h2-console I also see parent_id column but it contains all null values no matter what I do.

Comment: Javier RP, really nice explanation, I forgot the parent id part for DTO

Comment: If you accept the answer then it could help others to identify.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking children as string take them as a List of object.
Replace this:

```
private String children;
```

with

```
List<Alien> children;
```

and add method to add child

```
void addChild(Alien child) {
    if(this.children == null) {
        this.children = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    this.children.add(child);
}
```

Let say Hierarchy is

A

|_B

|_C

then create:

```
Alien c - new Alien();
Alien b = new Alien();
Alien a = new Alien();

b.addChild(c);
a.addChild(b);
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not able to see how I would get what I want by doing that. What if a child has children of its own? How do you establish the relationship between the grandparent and his grandson?

Comment: The same way, you can add child to children while creating its object, I recommend you to read about tree Data structure, its a simple tree of objects, You can even search create tree in java it will help

Comment: What parent id you are passing ? Also could you please check what queries it is printing.

Comment: updated the answer, If you want parent id, you can take a field in the same class.